# optimized way to scale image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following function that runs thought about 25 times and delays the site's load time by 10 seconds or more. What the code is essentially doing is working out the height when the image's width is scaled down or up to 310px. Any suggestions on how I could improve my code or suggest another option? Maybe jQuery might be better for this?

```
function img_height($image){
    $inputwidth = 310;

    list($width,$height) = getimagesize($image);
    if($width !== $inputwidth){
        $outputheight = ($inputwidth * $height)/ $width;
    }elseif($width == $inputwidth){
        $outputheight = $height;
    }
    return 'style="height:'.$outputheight.'px;" ';
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `elseif` simply use an `else`.

Comment: Are those images on your server or somewhere else?

Comment: @Wurstbro They are being pulled from imgur.

Comment: If you always get the same ones, make e.g. a mysql table where you put the sizes in. If you can't do that you should consider using m_curl, in case you don't use that already. I guess right now you load picture after picture from imgur. That's what takes so long.

Comment: I made something similar which saves the original sizes and the resized sizes in a table. No calculation needed when someone visits the page.

Answer (score 0):

@Enigmo - I have worked a lot with image loading and dynamically changing sizes. You really cannot make a big difference in the loading time using PHP. I would suggest you to use AJAX and preload the images or do a lazy loading. That way your site gets loaded first and then the images keep showing up as and when they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing images sizes alongside with the image names in some db structure (cache). Then, you would know already all the sizes and your site would work blazingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use jquery stuff to do this stuff as this will be getting fired at client browser and not making any load/processing on server side. also jquery is faster than php processing also